# How to load GIF image from drawable folder into ImageView using glide?

Tags: android, drawable, animated-gif, android-glide

I have to show load GIF image from drawable to ImageView using `glide`.I have tried with following.

```
Glide.with(LoginActivity.this)
                .load(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_gif)).asGif()
                .crossFade()
                .into(relativeLayout);
```

But isn't seem working and it's working when I'm place image in `raw` folder.but the problem is I have to use different dimension images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are tying to load image into a Relative Layout?

Comment: Some important links-
1. https://github.com/bumptech/glide
2. http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try to use Ion it works fine for me.
[Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)

*Using Ion*

```
 Ion.with(imgView)
.error(R.drawable.default_image)
.animateGif(AnimateGifMode.ANIMATE)
.load("file:///android_asset/animated.gif");
```

*Using Glide*

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.sample_gif).into(imageViewTarget);
```

*Another Approach*

For **Glide 3.0** you need to set `asGif()` earlier:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .asGif()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading2)
    .crossFade()
    .into(imageView);
```

Keep in mind that just using load() will load either a GIF or a Bitmap depending on the type of the data. Unless you want your load to fail if the given url is not a gif, you don't need to specify asGif()

Comment: It's an alternative solution.please answer for my query.

Comment: I have tried both of your code but no one is showing animation for me. I am using glide.

Comment: @Kristo What is GlideDrawableImageViewTarget?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS a target that can display an Drawable in an ImageView.

Comment: But I can't import it, where I can found it? I did compile the library tho

Comment: Use `DrawableImageViewTarget` to replace `GlideDrawableImageViewTarget` for newer Glide version

Comment: @Alston do you know why it's loading my gif as only an image? I did everything above and made sure to place my gif inside raw folder

Comment: @davids. So I told you for new Glide version, the API you choosed is deprecated. You need to use the new one above.

Answer (score 8):

Just pass the resource id directly to [load()](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.html#load(java.lang.Integer)):

```
Glide.with(LoginActivity.this)
            .load(R.drawable.bg_gif)
            .asGif()  // you may not need this
            .crossFade()
            .into(relativeLayout);
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me - I did write the code and execute it.  You may want to consider if your ImageView is correctly visible.

Answer (score 3):

### Steps to load Gif images from drawable

1. **You need to move your Gif image to`res/raw` folder of your project** 
   (
   if your project don't have `raw` folder in resource directly then simply make one and put your gif in it )
2. **and then you can simply load your gif with just one line of code**

> ```
> Glide.with(this)
>                   .load(R.raw.splash)
>                   .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(
>                           (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image)));
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Place your Gif in the "raw" folder and use

```
  GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
    Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.test).into(imageViewTarget);
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Glide 4**

```
GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(R.raw.gif_file)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .into(imageView);
```